# How to create an ArcGIS toolbox programmatically?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

Is it possible to programmatically create an ArcGIS toolbox?

The aim is to write a plugin that works in ArcGIS and have a single source for the tool parameters which is then compiled to an Arc toolbox app.

Alternatively is there a good workaround for this?  I note data interoperability in Arc fires up a second dialog from the toolbox dialog: can this be done from the tool validator?  As such a dialog could obviously be compiled by an external script, this (almost) fulfils the same purpose.

**CLARIFICATION** this question is about Arc toolboxes only, as I regard programmatic creation of QGIS/command line interfaces to be a solved problem already.

Comment: It is definitely possible to programmatically generate a Python Toolbox, it is just a text file with a .pyt extension.  The main piece would be handling the generation of parameter types and tool validation.  The source code that would actually need to be ran just goes in the `execute` method.

Comment: As @crmackey says, the ArcPy part of your question is certainly a Yes, but you have made it to broad by also asking about "QGIS, command line, etc", and even more so by asking about firing up a tool dialog from tool validation.  You may need to look into wxPython or Tkinter which are technologies that I do not work with myself.

Comment: if it's only the parameters which are dynamic, why not have a static toolbox/tool and just pass the parameters?

Comment: @crmackey nailed it - Python toolbox is the answer.  If you add that as an answer I'll accept.  I didn't know these existed, to date I have created toolboxes by pointing and clicking in ArcMap.  Are python toolboxes a recent addition to ArcGIS?

Comment: They were added at version 10.1, along with Python Add-Ins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, I would go with a [Python Toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001500000034000000).  These can be programmatically generated because they are just text files with a .pyt file extension.